# Testing for toString on Firebug console.log()s return value throws

Tags: firebug

The return value from a call to `console.log()` does not allow `toString`, though the `__exposedProps__` indicates that it should be allowed.

[image: result.toString fails on console.log()s return value]

**UPDATE:** Just wanted to add that I'm only looking to make it non-toxic, so thanks for the [fast response](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/commit/790572b5f5ce9fe218e1a779aebccb495de12d1c)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an [implementation detail](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/b435d53734674e5e991591c003a41a09477aee69/extension/content/firebug/console/console.js#L499) of Firebug. `console.log()` and the other functions of the [Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) are not supposed to have a return value.
When you try out your code in other devtools, you'll see that they return `undefined`.

The `toString()` function is actually part of Firebug's internal code and Firefox security mechanisms forbid websites and the command line access to it.
`console.dir()` still lists that function, because it is running within privileged scope.

The object `console.dir()` outputs on the result of Console API functions was implemented in [issue 6257](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6257).

[Issue 7774](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7774) was created to fix Firebug's behavior.

Comment: ... but it's still a fair point that `result.toString()` shouldn't throw. I'm sure that's due to various platform changes (`__exposedProps__` getting more and more deprecated). I might as well fix it, so I opened https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7774.

Comment: Exactly, the problem we were having is that even testing the response via `response.toString` caused it to throw